# Editor for all sorts of (Text) Files

Tags: text-editor, text-processing, language

The IT world is full of text files, for configuring things for defining things or for authoring text.

Since many years I've been searching a tool that can edit text files that have a user defined format. For example the Linux configuration file smb.conf is quite well structured:

```
[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /tmp
   printable = yes
   public = no
   writable = no
   create mode = 0700
```

Or consider such a language:

```
This is an example document
===========================
Section 1
---------
   Here we have some contents of section 1.
   
Section 2
---------
   And this is section 2. Here we have an attachment.
   
Attachment: data_04.zip
```

You could use markdown for such things. But not everybody wants it.

Or see a JSON file:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "isAlive": true,
  "age": 27,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
  }
}
```

Is there a configurable editor for such things in that way that it is so strict that it lets you only create legal files? If you have for example the mouse cursor at a position where you shouldn't write or if you want to write something, that is not legal it would not let you type.

Of course it will not work out of the box. The user must define the structure and some rules. But it should for example be possible to define a few context sensitive text templates, so that a tool can give me a comfortable editor for it. A grammar parser is not always the right choice. And a grammer parser does not give you an editor.

I tested so far Spoofax, Xtext and MPS. But these are all integrated into an extreme huge IDE (Eclipse or IntelliJ). And therefore they have thousands of functions, that you don't need when you just want to edit some simple text files. And you always have to use the compilation and packaging functions of the Java world. Everything does not feel like a smart editor, but more like a full development IDE.

But apart from this, especially MPS gives me exactly what I search. The editing functions are incredible. Everything is configurable with an own structure and text templates and rules and even auto completions. That tool is really impressive, and it is much fun using it. This is exactly what I search. But actually you can see everywhere that MPS is not an editor for text. It is an editor for data, where you have only an Abstract Syntax Tree in your hand. If I want to read and write text files, there is nothing that helps me. I have to write my own "persistency layer". And that is pure Java code. This is not handy. I want to use a template mechanism instead of writing a parser by hand. Even parser generators do not work, because my languages are not grammar based.

Are there any ideas? I could imagine that one of the Markdown editors could be adapted to support more than exactly one markdown format. But I have no idea.

What I have not yet tested is Racket, because so far I was not able to find out why it is so often recommended for language engineering.

And what in my opinion could also be worth trying is the syntax highlighting feature of a good text editor. But there are so many text editor in the world, and I would need one where the syntax highlighting feature is powerful enough to "parse" my text formats.

I could imagine that with Emacs such a major mode exist. But I haven't found something usable. I am not very familiar with Emacs, either. But I have the impression that Emacs people would not even want to produce text files. They understand as domain specific language a Lisp data structure and they are happy with everything being Lisp code. And writing an own Emacs Major mode is much work. Especially as I am nearly unfamiliar with Emacs or Lisp.

I would be very happy if any of you have an idea. I am software developer, so I can spend really a lot of time for implementing or adapting an existing tool. But so far I have just no idea of anything that goes to the direction, where I want to go. So I think, I would have to start from scratch.